# C# variable is used before it's value is determined

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

This code should take a piece of information from a webpage. My problem is that it doesn't show correnctly and don't know why.

I want to make it somehow to wait for document completion without creating a function outside that one.

The actual code that I want to fix from a larger file:

```
public static string GetNews()
{
    WebBrowser page = new WebBrowser();
    string data = null;
    page.Navigate(launcherScriptAddress);
    page.DocumentCompleted += delegate {
    data = page.Document.GetElementById("news").InnerText;
        // can't return `data` from here
    };
    return data; // returns null because it doesn't wait for document to be completed
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting your `MessageBox.Show` inside `delegate` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work the way you try to do it. Your function returns way before the page.DocumentCompleted-delegate is being executed.

So the only thing you can do is pass a callback to your GetNews-function that gets executed within your delegate.

The old problem with sync <-> async.

Besides, you should swap the statements .Navigate and .DocumentCompleted +=
to make sure "page" has the callback set before it even starts to load anything.

[edit]
To do that, you need to create a delegate and change your function:

```cs
public delegate void NewsCallback( string dataReceived );

public static void GetNews( NewsCallback callback )
{
    WebBrowser page = new WebBrowser();
    string data = null;
    page.Navigate(launcherScriptAddress);
    page.DocumentCompleted += delegate {
       data = page.Document.GetElementById("news").InnerText;
       callback( data );
    };
}
```

After that, you may want to call it this way:

```cs
void CallMyNews(){
    GetNews( (dataReceived) => {
      DoSomeStuffWith(dataReceived);
    } );
}
```

Comment: oh.. and how do i do that?

Comment: That is a little bit of work to do here, i will edit the answer accordingly